# Using type aliases to define type aliases

Tags: vb.net

As a fanatical believer in DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself), I just wrote this code:

```
Imports SimpleDict = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
Imports ListOfSimpleDicts = System.Collections.Generic.List(Of SimpleDict)
Imports DictOfSimpleDicts = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, SimpleDict)
```

I immediately get errors, "Type 'SimpleDict' is not defined." on the last two lines.  Is there no way to avoid having to repeat myself in my type aliases?

[Addendum] 24 hours later, I had to change SimpleDict to alias Dictionary(Of String, HashSet).  The good news is, since I'm using an alias, my change propagates to everywhere I've used it, but unfortunately I still need to change the other two lines myself.

Comment: you can't import Dictionary of type string, string directly. you should first import namespace into alias and then define variable for dictionary.
Imports SimpleDict = System.Colections.Generic

dim newDict as new Dictionary(of String, String)

Comment: I'm not declaring variables, I'm defining aliases for types, as documented here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/imports-statement-net-namespace-and-type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From the VB specification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/reference/language-specification/source-files-and-namespaces#imports-statement)

> Imports statements make names available in a source file, but do not
>   declare anything in the global namespace's declaration space. The
>   scope of the names imported by an Imports statement extends over the
>   namespace member declarations contained in the source file. The scope
>   of an Imports statement specifically does not include other Imports
>   statements, nor does it include other source files. **Imports statements
>   may not refer to one another.**
>
> In this example, the last Imports statement is in error because it is not affected by the first import
>   alias.
>
> ```
> Imports R1 = N1 ' OK.
> Imports R2 = N1.N2 ' OK.
> Imports R3 = R1.N2 ' Error: Can't refer to R1.
> ```

I'm not sure what you could do instead. The only thing I could think of is defining `SimpleDict` as a class of `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)`, not sure if this is ideal for you since you have to create a class.

```
Imports ListOfSimpleDicts = System.Collections.Generic.List(Of RootNamespace.SimpleDict)
Imports DictOfSimpleDicts = System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, RootNamespace.SimpleDict)

Public Class SimpleDict
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary(Of String, String)
End Class
```

Comment: I like your approach; it's better than anything I could come up with.  I'll play around with it and see how it works out.  I have some utility functions that I could make into methods, with would work well with this.